# Browserify failing on events dependency

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

My browserify gulp build is failing with the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^

SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

Events appears to be a browserify dependency. Everything else I've found on SO with this error was related to people using .es6 files, but I'm not. Seems to me like everything was working last night. It's a pretty simple build. Just straightforward .js files with a few requires. Sorry, I know that's not terribly specific… been looking for a while and can't seem to be able to nail it down. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using import instead of require for loading the modules? Please post the code that is causing the error.

Comment: I have 4 require statements in there. No imports. Should I try import? What's the difference? I don't know what code is causing the error. The error doesn't give me a file name or line number from my code. Events.js is a third party browserify dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, don't I feel sheepish.
On one of my modules I mis-typed the method call as:

```
export.module
```

instead of

```
module.exports
```

Comment: Would have been nice if that error message mentioned the line number or even file name where the problem was found. events.js at the beginning of that error message is just a browserify dependency, not my code.